# Access 2003/2007 : Query to find average of one text field grouped by another in table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, parameters

So lets say I have a table that looks something like this:

```
ItemName                ProductType
----------------------------------------------------------
Name1                   Type1
Name2                   Type1
Name3                   Type1
Name4                   Type2
Name5                   Type3
```

and so on for thousands of records. I want a sql statement to find the average number of Names per Types. I want to use it in vba, behind a form.

How would I go about this? I have the sneaking suspision that this is something simple that is escaping me right now.

EDIT: Sorry....a little unclear. I mean in a table like fashion, have the types listed out with a count for each of the relative Names

```
Averages
Type                Count of Names
-------------------------------------------
Type1                   5
Type2                   6
```

so basically see how many names applicable to types, what Inner Select statement should I use to accomplish this?

Thanks
Justin

Comment: This is confusing. Each product type in your table will have a particular number of names, rather than an average number of names. You can display how many (i.e. the count of) names there are in your table for each particular type, and then show the average for the grand total. But an average per type does not make sense.

Comment: actually that makes perfect sense....not sure what I was thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select avg( c ) from 
    ( select ProductType, count( ItemName ) c
    from myTable
    group by ProductType )
```

Comment: thanks very much....what if I wanted to list it out per ProductTypes? I mean show the individual average of ItemName(s) per ProductTypes

Comment: there is no average per type - you can run the inner select to see the count per type.

Comment: yes...you are right for sure. what I am looking for is not an average but a count for each name per relative type. apologies; thanks for your help.